# Unable to set project share group via Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I have a Gitlab Group created with (`Team A`) and wanted to invite the group to (`Project A`).  I can do it from the UI but when performing the action via Gitlab API, it failed with `{"message": "Not Found"}`.  I can use the following API with request `DELETE` to remove the group I added from UI.  But when trying to create it, i can't.  Did I miss anything ?

I am following the documentation here https://archives.docs.gitlab.com/14.10/ee/api/projects.html#share-project-with-group

```
curl --request POST --url "https://<gitlab url>/api/v4/projects/<project id>/share" \
  -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <redacted>" \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "@/tmp/payload.json"
```

My payload is simple

Group id is (`Team A`) and Group Access is `Developer`

```
{
    "group_id": 3523, 
    "group_access": 30
}
```

### Gitlab Info

GitLab Enterprise Edition `14.10.4-ee`

### Verbose curl

```
* Connected to gitlab  port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* Server certificate:
*  start date: Jul 20 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 17 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.x
> POST /api/v4/projects/<id>/share HTTP/1.1
> Host: <gitlab url>
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> PRIVATE-TOKEN: <redacted>
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 46
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Sat, 14 Oct 2023 17:45:38 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 23
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Vary: Origin
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Request-Id: 01HCQMPC5JQ5GYJBW5C80NN9S4
< X-Runtime: 0.071873
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< 
* Connection #0 to host <gitlab url> left intact
{"message":"Not Found"}%
```

**IMPORTANT** I am using the correct and existing project id, otherwise i wouldn't able to delete the share group from the project using Gitlab API.  I'm not sure why when trying to create, it says `404 Not Found`, that remains clueless to me.  If someone can help, would very much appreciated.

Below is a successful creation for share group via UI
[image]

Comment: I have deleted my answer as your payload is correct. I actually tried your payload now with one of my projects and group and I got a success(201) response. I also fired a DELETE share on the same group and project and executed the share API again and it was successful. So looks like the API is working as expected. In your case a message 'Not Found" in Gitlab can arise sometime with lack of permission. One question, the token you are using is of the same user who is able to successfuly add the group on the UI?

Comment: Yeah, same token.  I have also tried using a new token generated by the project `Access Token` itself, but still no success.  Pretty sure the token is correct, otherwise, `DELETE` wouldn't work.  I suspect the gitlab version I have could be the issue or bug

Comment: Yes, looking at everything you have said so far, and the difference in responses I get in 16.5 version vs your 14.10.4, looks like this is a version issue. Can you reach out to Gitlab support if possible?